# Assign new size to const char* using memset()

Tags: c++, c

I have declare buffer `const char* buf;`

Later on I want to re assign size using memset

```
buffer_len = 1024;
    memset(buf, '\0', buffer_len);
    buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';
```

gives error:

```
client.cpp:73:30: error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from client.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:62:14: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ [-fpermissive]
client.cpp:75:21: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(buf + (((sizetype)strlen(buf)) + -1u))’
```

I know it's due to `const` but is there any alternative or way to perform it event it is const?

Comment: Why are you using const if you want to change buffer?

Comment: If you wrote the code, I'd suggest trying to steer away from `char*` and old C style prtogtamming anyways. Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Is the code C or C++?

Comment: @Anonymous more look like [tag:C] and [tag:Pointers]

Comment: `memset()` doesn't change the size of anything. It changes the contents. Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I also feel you are confuse between `const char* buf;` and `char* const  buf;` : [const-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious the author is asking a solution for what he want to operate. And simply explanation of the comping error is satisfactory. I do not want to explain why the author's code is not compiling, cause the above answers explain very well about this.

I am try to give a solution if the author really want to do all the operations he meant in his code, though I do not recommend to do that in real world software project.

Use [const_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) to remove the const property of the variable:

```
const char* buf;
...
buffer_len = 1024;
...
char *ptr = const_cast<char *>(buf);
memset(ptr, '\0', buffer_len);
ptr[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';
```

Comment: -1: This does not address the problem of the OP one bit. See other answers.

Comment: @cmaster Do not know you are talking about. You can point out what is wrong with the code if you think you understand the question. I need your detail.

Comment: The problem is that we can be 99% sure that his buffer was never allocated to contain 1024 bytes.

Comment: @cmaster No, you can't be sure. He is just give a part of his code. Some code is omited. That is why I give "..." in my code.

Comment: Which is why I didn't say 100% ;-) But unless we have any evidence that he actually took care of the size of the buffer, I believe it is dangerous to just give a way around the compiler warning (and thus not helpful).

Comment: You are talking something that @Karimkhan is not asking. And We can't suppose he do not take care of memory allocating. You are fabricating a question that do not exist in his code.

Comment: @cmaster And by the way, I did not try to "just give a way around the compiler warning", instead I try to make the intended operation viable.

Comment: If I cannot convince you by his line "I want to re assign size using memset", I won't be able to. So I won't prolong this discussion any more.

Comment: @cmaster OK. We are talking in a different world, but you can see what I mean from the comment under your question, that is "re assign size" meant to modify buffer_len value, and I am trying to make the successive operation viable.

Comment: @lulyon: What is the drawback of using `const_cast`?

Comment: @Karimkhan const_cast is by definition used to add or remove const or volatile property of a variable. The drawback or otherwise, advantage is just like that of the c/c++ language, that is, you have more control of what your code do, but you have to do everything carefully. So that depends on how you are using it.

Comment: @lulyon: thanks, till today I just knew "const var can not be modified". But I think we can use it if it does not affect other code!

Comment: @Karimkhan Yes, and It is my pleasure to know that helps.

Answer (score 5):

The assignment `buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';`  is invalid because you defined `buf` as const: `const char* buf;` Read compiler's error message: `error: assignment of read-only location`.

---

One point: You set `buf` with nul `\0` so length of buf is `0` (`\0` at zero index) then if *suppose*  you *don't* declare `buf` as const even then you would be assiging at negative index because `strlen(buf) - 1`  == `0 - 1` = `-1` – Undefined behaviour

Comment: @user814064 yes that I added in second part.

Comment: For OP: I think before/better to answer read compiler messages.

Comment: @AlterMann Ohh I acknowledged today morning only. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`memset` does not assign size. It fills a buffer with bytes. Filling a buffer declared as `const char*` makes no sense, since the reason you declare it const is for *yourself* not to write to it.

You could create a different array instead, since this `const` does not prevent you from changing the pointer itself.

Reassigning size should probably be called reallocating memory, you can use one of `malloc`, `calloc` or others to do it. Or since you've tagged this with c++, probably using the `new` operator would be the best idea.

Comment: Since you mention `malloc` and `calloc`, you should probably also mention `realloc`, which is closest to what I think the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve flexible strings in C is to use `realloc`:

```
//Get some malloc'ed strings.
char* myString = asprintf("my cool, malloc()-allocated string\n");
char* myOtherString = asprintf("Oh, and by the way: Hello World!\n");

//Make room in myString to append the other string.
size_t finalStringSize = strlen(myString) + strlen(myOtherString);
myString = realloc(myString, finalStringSize + 1);   //+1 for termination

//Concatenate the strings
strcat(myString, myOtherString);
free(myOtherString), myOtherString = NULL;
```

But, of course, using C++ std::strings should be less of a hassle.

Comment: Is there any single implication that the author didn't allocate memory? This is not even related to what he is asking.

Comment: @lulyon Yes, there is: "I want to re assign size using memset" My example shows the use of `realloc()` to achieve precisely that.

Comment: "re assign size" does not mean re allocate memory. the size variable `buffer_len` is independent of the actual allocated memory.